# How to set up debugging on VSCode Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

If anyone has a debugger set up on VSCode on Mac OSX, is the process as simple as launch.json and tasks.json file? I've spent so long trying to figure out how to set up a debugger and I can't seem to get it. When the debugger runs, I am unable to step into, step out, etc. Any help would be appreciated.

For a bit of context, this is what appears in my debug console:

```
=library-unloaded,id="/Users/SamRoo/Computer Contest C++/PracticeProblems/Firehose",target-name="/Users/SamRoo/Computer Contest C++/PracticeProblems/Firehose",host-name="/Users/SamRoo/Computer Contest C++/PracticeProblems/Firehose"
```

This is followed by a bunch of "Symbols loaded" statements.

Comment: Did you compile with debug info enabled? Did you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: @Alan Birtles Yes, I followed the documentation quite precisely. What do you mean by compile with debug info enabled?

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't really know how to make a minimal reproducible example I'm a noob, but I have a feeling this may be the issue. Under the "args" section of the tasks.json file, do I need to specify the file directory?

Comment: "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],

Comment: That's what I have right now

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?